# Резиновый footer

Tags: html, css

В `css` документе для `body` прописан параметр `width:1024px`.

Но в то же время я хочу сделать `footer` резиновым, то есть `width:100%`. Как достичь такого эффекта?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создать новый id типа #wrapper и задать ему ширину width:1024px, с body эту ширину конечно же убрать! Все что заключено в `<body></body>` заключить в `<div id="wrapper"></div>`
footer разместить ниже #wrapper и будет счастье!

Comment: спасибо) буду пробовать